# If $f$ is entire and nowhere zero, then there exists an entire function $g$ such that $f(z)=g(z)^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

**Problem:** Show that if $f$ is entire and nowhere zero, then there exists an entire function $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z)^2$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

**Preliminary:** To get some practice in, I tried to solve an analogous problem showing that there exists an entire $g$ such that $f=e^g$:

To find such $g$: we different both sides to get $f' = g' e^g = g' f \Rightarrow \frac{f'}{f} = g'$. Since entire functions on a simply connected space have an antiderivative, this implies that $f = e^{g + c} = Ce^g$ for some constant $C$. So there is an entire function $g$ such that $f = e^g$ as desired.

**Attempt on the original problem:** I seem unable to apply the same technique as the $f=e^g$ proof. That is, if $f=g^2$ then $f' = 2gg'$ so we have to stop here. Furthermore, considering $\sqrt{f(z)} = g(z)$ seem illegal because we have to consider a branch cut: this is a problem because Picard's little theorem tells us that if $f$ is non-constant entire that doesn't hit the value $0$, then the range is $f(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ so there isn't an appropriate branch cut we can really take.

What can I do here? One intuitive guess is if I know $f = e^h$ for some entire $h$, then I can consider $g = e^{h/2}$ so that $g^2 = e^h = f$ and this helps us avoid the "square-root branch cut" issue?

Comment: What problems do you run into attempting to make the $g(z) = \exp\left(\frac 12 h(z)\right)$ idea into a complete proof?

Comment: @aschepler I am not confident with these problems because I am not well-versed with branch cuts yet. But here's an attempt: Say we have an entire $h$ such that $e^h = f$ (proven in Preliminary). Since $h$ is entire, $\frac{1}{2}h$ is entire. Since $e^z$ is entire as well, $\exp (\frac{1}{2} h(z))$ is also entire. So $f = \exp (\frac{1}{2} h(z))^2$. Is this OK? Thank you.

Comment: @aschepler What I wrote sounds OK and rigorous... I guess I just need to be more confident.

Comment: That sounds good. I would make the preliminary lemma part clearer: you're going from statements you would like to be true about some unknown $g$, then using the antiderivative theorem to say that $\int f'/f$ does exist, then show that setting $g$ to any such antiderivative does satisfy the desired $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$.

Comment: In that proof, the branch cut of the square root only comes up in the fact that $g(z) = -\exp\left(\frac 12 h(z)\right)^2$ is another solution. Since we're making one consistent choice for all $z$, rather than a choice at each $z$, this is fine.

Comment: @aschepler So for the preliminary: $f$ is entire implies that $f'$ is also entire. Since $f$ is nonzero, we can take the quotient to get an entire function $f'/f$. Since entire functions on a simply connected domain has an antiderivative, it follows that there exists an entire $g$ such that $f = e^g$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following @aschepler 's comments, here is the solution:

Suppose $f$ is entire and nonzero. Then, $f'$ is also an entire function. Since $f$ is nonzero, we can take the quotient to get another entire function $f'/f$. Since this entire function is defined on $\mathbb{C}$ (by definition) which is simply connected, it has an antiderivative. Consequently there exists an entire $h$ such that $f = e^h$.

Therefore, $g = e^{h/2}$ is an entire function since $h/2$ is entire and the composition of two entire functions (namely $h/2$ and $e^z$) is entire. Observe that $g^2 = e^h = f$ so we are done.

Comment: "... it has an antiderivative $h$. That is, $h'(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ for all $z$." But this still doesn't show $f(z) = e^{h(z)}$ - and in fact that's only true for some of the antiderivatives.